# Simulate the number of times a random condition is met in n attempts

Tags: probability, simulation

If every time a condition is evaluated, there is exactly an `x` chance of it succeeding (`RAND() < x`), is there any way to simulate this formula `n` times, in order to get the number of successes?

I'm *not* asking about an average, although, if the formula worked as expected, higher values of `n`would have results getting closer to the average.

Bit of background info:

I'm addressing this from a programming perspective, so the simple (yet expensive) solution would be to iteration `i = 0 to n`, evaluate `RAND() < x`, and count the number of successes.

However, I'll be dealing with quite varied values of `n`, from very low, to quite high, and performance will be quite critical. Evaluating `RAND()` 1,000,000 times just to simulate this is quite unideal.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to simulate. You can compute the probability of $k$ successes in $n$ trials using the binomial formula or the normal approximation (for large $n$).